# How to create a valueBox in R Shiny when data is missing?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app similar to the example below.

[image]

I'm using `valueBox()` to return some values that correspond to a particular variable in the data. In this instance, I've just used *Left* and *Right* as an example where the boxes are coloured based on whether the value is larger than 100. The issue I'm running into is when I select a name from the dropdown that isn't present in the data it returns an ugly error in the dashboard body, just like the additional image below.

[image]

My preference is for a value box to still be visible even if data is missing for a particular variable and/or name. Yes, I could edit the names from the dropdown menu, but this is not an option as I require all possible names to be present. I'd like the value box to read something like ***NA*** instead of the specific value with the name of the intended variable (e.g., *Left* or *Right*) as the subtitle (just like the ones in the first image). All of this would go on a white background, too. This would then look a lot cleaner for other end-users viewing my app.

Does anyone have any workarounds or solutions for this particular problem using my example data/code below?

**Example code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

# Unique names for dropdown list.
names <- paste("Name", LETTERS[1:10])

# Example data.
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  name = rep(paste("Name", LETTERS[c(1:6, 9:10)]), times = 2),
  date = rep(Sys.Date() + sample(1:10, 8), times = 2),
  var = c(rep("Left", 8), rep("Right", 8)),
  value = round(rnorm(16, 100, 20), 1)
  )

##### APP #####

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example App"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tab One",
               tabName = "tab1")
      )
    ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
            fluidRow(
              box(selectInput("name", "Select Name:",
                              names,
                              selected = "Name A",
                              multiple = FALSE),
                  width = 12),
              valueBoxOutput("box1", width = 2),
              valueBoxOutput("box2", width = 2)
              )
            )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output){
  
  x <- reactive({
    dat %>%
      filter(name == input$name)
    })
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = first(x()$value),
             subtitle = "Left",
             color = ifelse(first(x()$value) >= 100, "green", "red")
             )
  })
  
  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(value = last(x()$value),
             subtitle = "Right",
             color = ifelse(last(x()$value) >= 100, "green", "red")
    )
  })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Just set the value of the `valueBox`es using an `ifelse` that tests the number of rows I of `x()`, similar to what you’ve done for their `color` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested by @Limey use an `if` or `ifelse` to account for any `NA` values. However, as `"white"` isn't a valid color (see the error message) I used `"black"` for the NA case:

```
set_color <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    return("black")
  }
  if (x >= 100) "green" else "red"
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- reactive({
    dat %>%
      filter(name == input$name)
  })

  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = first(x()$value),
      subtitle = "Left",
      color = set_color(first(x()$value))
    )
  })

  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = last(x()$value),
      subtitle = "Right",
      color = set_color(last(x()$value))
    )
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @stefan. This is great. Only thing with the code you have very kindly provided is values below 100 don't appear red like in my original example. Is there an additional trick to have this occur?

Comment: Hm. Weird. Works fine on my side, e.g. for Name E I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B76f.png